# Azure Container Registry without Pull authentication (ACR Pull Role)

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I have Azure Container Registry instance, where the container images are pushed. We have ACRPush role to some crdentials(service principal account)
Can we pull the images from the ACR without any authentication. We want to make this publicly available to pull images without any docker login/authentication.

Regards
Jayashree

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some things you need to understand carefully. First, the ACR is a private registry, so you must have the credential with the right permission to push and pull images. Second,  the `docker login` is just a method to set the credential for the registry, so it's not necessary.

According to the above things, you do not need to run `docker login` command, but you must have a credential for the ACR. You can run the Azure CLI command `az acr login --name acr_name` and this command will set the credential for docker without running `docker login`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure CLI, you can update the registry to allow anonymous pull using

```
az acr update --anonymous-pull-enabled ...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_update